# jQuery-ajax html decoding

Tags: jquery

I have a div who needs to filled with an html table through an ajax call.

Html:

```
<div id="showIdDiv"></div>
```

js:

```
$.ajax({
url: '../include/showIdDesc.php', 
success: function(data) { $("#showIdDiv").html(data); },
data: {id: id,numPerPage: numPerPage},
dataType: "html"
});
```

The php script is a just building a table from db.

This is what I get in response (from firebug console) which is what I want:

```
<br ><br ><table class="listings"><caption> You Selected Id - melon_c10127:</caption><tr class='colNames'><th>ID</th><th>Description uniprot</th><th>Uniprot Name</th><th>Cluster</th></tr><tr><td>melon_c10127</td><td>No Matching Hit found</td><td class="alignText"><a href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/" target="_blank"></a></td><td class="alignText"><a href="cluster.php?query_type=cluster&id=melon_c10127&numPerPage=10&page=0&cluster_search=6">6</a></td></tr></table><br ><br ><br >
```

But this is what the browser is showing:

```
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="listings"/>
<h4/>
You Selected Id - 14235:IDDescription uniprotUniprot NameCluster14235
<a href="" target="_blank"/>
<a href="cluster.php?query_type=cluster&id=14235&numPerPage=10&page=0&cluster_search=2"/>
2
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

It's looks like it's not decoding the html elements correct.
It happens on all the browsers.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks...

I tried doing a test:

html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../test.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
<button onclick="test1()">test</button>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

test

js:

```
function test1()
{
    $.ajax({
           url: '../test2.php', 
           success: function(data) { $("#test").html(data); },
           dataType: "html"
           });
}
```

php:

```
<?php

echo "<table>";
echo "<caption>test</caption>";
echo "<th>test1</th><th>test1</th><th>test1</th><th>test1</th>";
echo "<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Really the most basic script but I get the same results as my original question.
So it's probably not html markup error.

Thanks again...

Comment: Sorry, my bad about the invalid html tags I fixed it.. Still it's not working...

Comment: try removing the dataType: "html" from your ajax call

Comment: try alerting the data? put alert(data); just tbefore $("#showIdDiv").html(data);

Comment: Tried it, I get the same thing the firebug console show.

Comment: if the data variable holds the correct HTML then the $.ajax call has suceeded. This means there must be some error in your site's html markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently I had a defect in my jQuery file. Once I downloaded the file again all was well.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is invalid (e.g. you cannot have a `<h4>` element as a child element of a `<table>`) and the browser is attempting error recovery.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest `<h4>` elements directly inside `<table>` elements, that is why you HTML is not getting rendered properly.

Move the `<h4>` out of the table and try again!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `<h4>` tag inside a `<table>` tag like that.

Your browser is catching the error and trying to correct it, that's why you're seeing `</table>`